# how to run test on img tag while doing unit testing with enzyme on react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

i am doing unit testing with enzyme, and i am not able to select the image tag into the find()....so i am getting this error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

```
  34 |         //const sb = shallow(<sliderBanner store={store} />);
  35 |         //expect(Wrapper.find(<img />)).to.have.property("img");
> 36 |         expect(Wrapper.getElement("img")).to.have.property("src");
     |         ^
  37 |     });
  38 | });"
```

i have written this test case....

```
test("imgage source is valid", () => {
        const Wrapper = shallow(<MainBanner store={store} />);
        //const sb = shallow(<sliderBanner store={store} />);
        //expect(Wrapper.find(<img />)).to.have.property("img");
        expect(Wrapper.getElement("img")).to.have.property("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a `.find()` operator and then extracting the `src` attribute from it using `.prop(key)` method, following up with the assertion:

```
test("image source is valid", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MainBanner store={store} />);

  expect(wrapper.find('img').prop('src')).toEqual('some src value here');
}
```